# Good ways to earn money in Toussaint

Tags: the-witcher-3

One thing the new Blood & Wine expansion for the Witcher 3 brought are a few new ways to spend some serious coin. I managed to barely affort a set of Grandmaster Witcher armor, but only by spending everything I had in coins and selling a significant amount of the more expensive crafting ingredients.

Now I'm standing in my fancy new estate, Corvo Bianco, but I'm too broke to afford renovating it.

I'm guessing there are also new ways to earn coin, and not only to spend it in this expansion. So what are some efficient ways to earn more money in Toussaint?

Comment: I haven't got that far into Blood & Wine yet but there does seem to a lot of jewelry and expensive armor and swords to be found in the usual places.

Comment: Nothing ever gets easier, does it? That's part of the fun of the game. Take contracts, search locations, gather loot and sell it, craft potions and sell them. Yeah, it's hard work, but it's also part of playing the game, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So what are some efficient ways to earn more money in Toussaint?

Well, **in** Toussaint there are **no** specific **new** ways to make money.

There are the traditional ways:

- Doing and cashing in Witcher Contracts
- Exploring the **"Unexplored Places"** (question marks) on the map
- Side-Quests
- Looting and selling

But in Toussaint there is some really interesting and good loot to sell and get good money from.

Spread throughout Toussaint there are open Houses (normal houses where people live in). **These houses are filled with jewellery like necklaces, rings, etc (Some even have diamonds lying about).**

So I found myself getting almost **3000** just from loot of 3/4 houses. I consider that to be pretty good. So if you wish to explorer a bit feel free to get the loot off these houses and put it to good use.

---

**P.S:** There is also a "naughty" way to make money found after patch 1.2 (Blood & Wine)

You can perform the bee-hive glitch with Willis in White Orchard to get yourself a **huge** amount of money in a really low amount of time.

I didn't do it myself because I wanted more of a fend for myself experience but you can do whatever you want so I'll put it here for the sake of spreading knowledge. **In the future this bug may be patched out**

[Willis - Beehive Bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEt9zsOqQVQ)

Since the video can be brought down I will explain what it consists of:

1. First go talk to Willis in White Orchard (You must have done his quest to unlock his shop)
2. Buy whatever you can from him (the more money Willis has, the better)
3. After giving him all your money go next to the hut by the river close to Willis and there should be a beehive in the trees. If there isn't one meditate for 1/2 hours.
4. Knock the beehive down with **Aard** and continue taking it through to Willis. When you're close to the village make sure you bring the beehive through the back (from Willis back) so that you **Aard** isn't blocked.
5. Once close make sure you put the beehive close to Willis so that the bees kill the NPC.
6. When he dies he falls to the ground and drops **everything** he owns (his money too).
7. Meditate for 1 hour and he will respawn and die again (the other body doesn't disappear neither does the loot)
8. Do this a few times and you can loot all the money from all the multiple Willis NPC's on the floor.

Summing it all up, if Willis has 15000 and you do the procedure 20 times you can make 300 000 in under 5 minutes.

Comment: so THAT is the origin story of the [guy made of bees](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Guy_Made_Of_Bees)!

Answer (score 2):

If you're rather high in level (38-40) you can get a small fortune from looting corpses over at Hanse Base by the Arthach Palace Ruins. Lots of enemies spawn so heads up, but the maces that the bandits drop there sell for between 83-150 crowns, swords for ~210 crowns over at the Grandmaster smith. Kill enough of them and you can get 1000-2000 crowns from it per run.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt work anymore patched for 1.22

For Blood and Wine Update 1.22+

New Glitch is the Infinite Sword Glitch
Head to head to

Location:Head to the Kaer Morhen Watchtower-
     -Open your Map and you will see a Small
       Square House South of the First Road
    Below the Fast Travel Icon in Kaer Morhen and 
       North of the Banking River in the map.

Best way to Head there: Fast Travel to Bastion       the Castle west of Kaer Morhen and Horse Ride till you Read an Intersection in thr Middle Take the Path Right towards the Watch Tower.

Infinate Sword Glitch:

- One at the Watch Tower take the Ladder up
   The first floor to see a dead body..
   -Loot the Relic Sword Pang of Concience      worth 937'Crowns
     -SAVE THE GAME after obtaining Sword
     -See the Beautiful View infront of you?
      Take the LEAP OF DEATH 
        -Load the Recent Save
  And you shouls have TWO SWORDS AND REPEAT
  This method is Repeatable for Multiple 
  SWORDS ENJOY YOUR NEW REVENUE
     -